# How to change dimensions of SVG and print it as PNG?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have an svg file, which contains a small vector. It looks like this:

[image: Tiny Vector]

I have the following code which converts SVG to PNG:

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel("transparent"));
$imagick->readImageBlob(file_get_contents($_GET['src']));
$imagick->setImageFormat('png32');

// Print
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $imagick;

$imagick->clear();
$imagick->destroy();

return;
```

Which is accessible using: `http://localhost/imagick.php?src=Untitled-1.svg`

And I want to resize the SVG and keep the quality, like Wikipedia does, for example:

`http://localhost/imagick.php?src=Untitled-1.svg&dimensions=[250]` Or `http://localhost/imagick.php?src=Untitled-1.svg&dimensions=[250,250]`

and then to print it with the new dimensions:

```
if (isset($_GET['dimensions'])) {
    $_GET['dimensions'] = json_decode($_GET['dimensions']);
    $imagick->resizeImage(
        (isset($_GET['dimensions'][0]) ? $_GET['dimensions'][0] : 0),
        (isset($_GET['dimensions'][1]) ? $_GET['dimensions'][1] : 0),
        Imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,
        0.5
    );
}
```

But when I do it, The quality is REALLY BAD:

[image: Awful Quality]

How can I preserve the original quality so it will be something like:

[image: Way much better quality]

?

Full Code:

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel("transparent"));
$imagick->readImageBlob(file_get_contents($_GET['src']));

if (isset($_GET['dimensions'])) {
    $_GET['dimensions'] = json_decode($_GET['dimensions']);
    $imagick->resizeImage(
        (isset($_GET['dimensions'][0]) ? $_GET['dimensions'][0] : 0),
        (isset($_GET['dimensions'][1]) ? $_GET['dimensions'][1] : 0),
        Imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,
        0.5
    );
}

$imagick->setImageFormat('png32');

// Print
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $imagick;

$imagick->clear();
$imagick->destroy();

return;
```

Comment: Set the resolution larger than 72 (say 244 for 2x or 288 for 4x) **before** reading the PDF

Comment: @fmw42 Working, Thanks!

Comment: The default resolution is 72 dpi, so I think Fred has a typo and actually 144 dpi is double, and 288 is 4 times,